# inner date query inefficiency

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a query and I need to add date range in the where clause. It should not be hardcoded therefore I used it like below. But it takes quite longer than hardcoded version.

```
tbl1.date >= ( SELECT 
   trunc( (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)), 'MM')
  from dual) and tbl1.date <= ( SELECT 
   last_day( (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)))
  from dual)
```

Same query with hardcoded date takes much shorter time

```
tbl1.date >= '16/05/01' and tbl1.date <= '16/05/31'
```

So how can I optimize the query which is not hardcoded?

Comment: Why are you using subqueries to get those values? Also does your date column include times that aren't midnight?

Comment: Alex is right. that can be rewritten to `tbl1.date between trunc( (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)), 'MM') and last_day( (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1))`

Comment: it solved my problem. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use subqueries:

```
tbl1.date >= trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
and tbl1.date <= last_day(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1))
```

or (though I don't really like this construct with dates, as it's easy to overlook the time part):

```
tbl1.date between trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
    and last_day(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1))
```

Or if your date column has values which are not midnight:

```
tbl1.date >= trunc(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
and tbl1.date < trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Whether that fixes your performance issue is another matter...